# Kafka 10 rebalancing Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running the kafka version of 0.10.1.1 and the clients are using the client version of 0.10.2.0.

There is a topic with 20 partitions. The consumers are running on 2 servers with the same consumer group and 10 consumers on each server.

When we start the server with 10 consumers on each server, it never consumes message and lots of rebalancing happening on the server( Not sure why rebalancing is happening in this case as the number of threads and partitions are exactly matching).
when we start with 1 consumer it starts consuming messages but keep getting commit failed exception message. We would like to have 10 consumers on each server.  Below is our consumer config,

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
enable.auto.commit = true
partition.assignement.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
auto.offset.reset = latest
check.crcs = true
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.mx = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = testGroupId
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 50
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metrics.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 50000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocol = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = Sun509
.... SASL and SSL related properties
```

Is exclude.internal.topics = true causing issue as kafka uses __consumer_offsets topic for offset management?

I dont understand why rebalancing is happening with 10 consumers on each server.

Thanks

Comment: How frequently are you calling poll()? If your consumers do  not call poll() every max.poll.interval.ms (5 minutes in your case) then they will get kicked out of the consumer group and trigger a rebalancing.

Comment: Also you have the heartbeat.interval.ms at 3 seconds and session.timeout.ms at 50 seconds so if there is a network outage or a Java GC event that stops any one of your consumers from sending a heartbeat for 50 seconds then again it will get kicked out of the consumer group and trigger rebalancing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I dont think GC will take more than 50 secs. This is happening only for a specific topic. I suspect the settings. Do I need update the value for any setting?

Comment: What WARN/INFO/ERROR messages do you get on the broker when you run the app and get commit failed?

Comment: How long did you wait for the rebalancing to be stable or the group is rebalancing all the time?  Since you have 10 consumer instances within a group, there might indeed require a quite long time for the group to be stable, so try to await a little long time. Besides, are there any obvious exceptions thrown on both the clients and server sides?

Comment: Does it take much time for rebalancing when there are multiple consumers in  a group in the same instance? Is there any property value to be increased so that the rebalance gets completed and all the consumer starts without any issues?